# Regular Expression for time in MVC4

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, time, data-annotations

I want to accept time in a text field with format like "12:15 AM" or "05:15 PM", except this nothing would be allowed to enter in the text field. So what will be the regular expression for it. I need to validate on both server and client sides in MVC4. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Anything u have tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some jquery plugin in the client side :-

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples

Comment: I have already added the plugin for taking time input, I just need validation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following *regex*

```
/(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\s*[AP]M/
```

check it in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/pO5wH7)